# Vectorize 2D character array column-wise

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a 2D numpy array like the following:

```
a=np.array([["Science", "Blue", 3],
            ["Math", "Red", 4],
            ["Math", "Red", 5],
            ["Science", "Red", 3]])
```

And I need to convert it into numeric values column wise, like the following (desired output):

```
out=np.array([[0, 0, 0],
              [1, 1, 1],
              [1, 1, 2], 
              [0, 1, 0]])
```

However, for downstream interpretability, I also need to have an output to trace back from the numeric values to the original values. I was thinking something like this:

```
trace_back_dict = {0: {0: "Science", 1: "Math"}, 
                   1: {0: "Blue", 1: "Red"}, 
                   2: {0: 3, 1: 4, 2: 5}}
```

Where the outer keys are the column indices from the original array and the inner dicts give the mapping of numeric: character value.

Is there an easy way of doing this, preferably something in `sklearn` style, where I can do a `fit_transform`, and then `transform` (for train and test set purposes)?

I was looking at `sklearn`'s `LabelEncoder`, and essentially what I need is to apply a different one on each column. Any suggestions on how to do this efficiently?

Thanks!

Jack

Comment: Do you really care that Science = 0 and Math = 1, or would any such mapping work?

Comment: @DSM Any such mapping will work. This was just an example case, these are not the actual data I am working with :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use an [OrdinalEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html):

```
In [25]: a = [['Science', 'Blue', 3], ['Math', 'Red', 4], ['Math', 'Red', 5], ['Science', 'Red', 3]]

In [26]: enc = sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder()

In [27]: enc.fit(a)
Out[27]: OrdinalEncoder(categories='auto', dtype=<class 'numpy.float64'>)

In [28]: enc.transform(a)
Out[28]: 
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 1., 2.],
       [1., 1., 0.]])

In [29]: enc.categories_
Out[29]: 
[array(['Math', 'Science'], dtype=object),
 array(['Blue', 'Red'], dtype=object),
 array([3, 4, 5], dtype=object)]

In [30]: trace_back_dict = {i: dict(enumerate(v)) for i, v in enumerate(enc.categories_)}

In [31]: trace_back_dict
Out[31]: {0: {0: 'Math', 1: 'Science'}, 1: {0: 'Blue', 1: 'Red'}, 2: {0: 3, 1: 4, 2: 5}}
```