# Encode character columns as ordinal but keep numeric columns the same

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a data frame like the following:

```
test = {"viral": "pos", "Status": "positive", "Age": 59, "score": 5}
test2 = {"viral": "neg"}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([test, test2])
```

I want to encode the character columns (viral, Status) as ordinal numbers, but leave the numeric values alone. Desired output is a numpy array with the same column names.

If I use OrdinalEncoder from sklearn, it does not deal with NaN values. Even if there were not NaN values, it would still ordinal encode the numeric columns also however. I want to fill NaN values with 0 in character columns but keep NaN in numeric columns.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Desired output (in numpy array):

```
    Age    Status  score viral
0  59.0         1    5.0     1
1   NaN         0    NaN     0
```

Thanks!
Jack

EDIT: I would also like a mapping from encoded value to original value like `{i: dict(enumerate(v)) for i, v in enumerate(enc.categories_)}` when using `enc=OrdinalEncoder()` (see [Vectorize 2D character array column-wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53142301/vectorize-2d-character-array-column-wise/53142401#53142401))

Comment: How are you meant to know `pos` and `positive` both map to `1`? Or is that just a coincidence, i.e. not a requirement?

Comment: @jpp Not a requirement :) Doesn't really matter how the numbers are mapped as long as I can get a mapping back of original value to final encoded value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`LabelEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)

```
enc = sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

mask = df.dtypes.eq(np.object)
df.loc[:, mask] = df.loc[:, mask].astype(str).apply(enc.fit_transform)
```

---

For you to be able to [`inverse_transform`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.inverse_transform), you can create use a `defaultdict` of `LabelEncoders`. The `key` is your choice. I'd suggest using the column name: intuitive and simple

```
from collections import defaultdict
enc = defaultdict(sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder)

mask = df.dtypes.eq(np.object)
df.loc[:, mask] = df.loc[:, mask].astype(str).apply(lambda s: enc[s.name].fit_transform(s))

    Status  viral
0   1       1
1   0       0
```

To [`inverse_transform`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.inverse_transform)

```
df.loc[:, mask].apply(lambda s: enc[s.name].inverse_transform(s))

    Status      viral
0   positive    pos
1   NaN         neg
```

Comment: I realized I should have specified this earlier (I added this to the question as an edit) but is it possible to get a mapping of encoded value to original value?

Answer (score 2):

Update, when there is NaN it will cat the code as -1 , if you need NaN you can convert back by using `replace`

```
df=pd.DataFrame([test,test2])
df.dtypes
Out[152]:
Age       float64
Status     object
score     float64
viral      object
dtype: object
listc=df.columns[df.dtypes=='object']

for x in listc:
    df[x]=df[x].astype('category').cat.codes

df
Out[156]: 
    Age  Status  score  viral
0  59.0       0    5.0      1
1   NaN      -1    NaN      0
```

Comment: I want this to be scalable, not always going to be just pos or neg, but any character value. Consider another column color with values possible of "blue", "green", "yellow". Again, that is not the intended use, so a scalable solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you downvote , would you like to leave a reason why ?

Comment: @JackArnestad Thanks, is there an easy way to get the mapping of number to initial value? Perhaps similar to `{i: dict(enumerate(v)) for i, v in enumerate(enc.categories_)}` when using `enc=OrdinalEncoder()` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53142301/vectorize-2d-character-array-column-wise/53142401#53142401). Thanks again!

Comment: `listc = df.select_dtypes(['object'])` might be considered idiomatic :)